# Preenchimento automático de inputs no formulário de edição com os dados antigos

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Bom, eu estou usando o node.js e o mongoose (mongoDB) como framework para o banco de dados. No front-end estou usando o handlebars. O problema é que os inputs ficam vazios mesmo passando como parâmetro o objeto. Abaixo o código em javaScript e o formulário:

```
// Código em javaScript que renderiza o formulário de edição
router.get('/categorias/edit/:id', (req, res) =>{
    Categoria.findOne({_id:req.body.id}).then((categoria)=>{
    res.render('adm/editCategoria', {categoria: categoria})
}).catch((err)=>{
    req.flash('error_msg', 'Essa categoria não existe')
    res.redirect('/adm/categorias')
})




// Formulário de edição para categorias  
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="/adm/categorias/nova" method="POST">
            <labFel for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Da Categoria" class="form-control" value="{{categoria.nome}}">
            <label for="slug">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="Slug Da Categoria" class="form-control" value="{{categoria.slug}}"><br>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirmar</button>
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem que ver se na página (listagem dessas categorias) que chama esta página de edição você passa um **id** como parâmetro na url.

Comment: Então, olha como que fica a url do botão: "/adm/categorias/edit/id:5d6c5e3b528afa0f74d7631a", mas quando clico aparece o erro: Essa categoria não existe, erro: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "id:5d6c5e3b528afa0f74d7631a" at path "_id" for model "categorias"

Comment: Teria que postar os códigos completos referentes ao problema, só assim para se ter uma ideia.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver, estava no botão que levava o link para esse form, não estou muito familiarizado com a linguagem, esse projeto é justamente para praticar. Mas basicamente foi uma confusão, o correto seria: 

href='/adm/categorias/edit/{{_id}}'

mas eu coloquei:

href='/adm/categorias/edit/{{:id}}'

Muito obrigado por tentar ajudar :D

Comment: Legal que resolveu, comentei para postar os códigos pois deduzi que provavelmente o erro estava em algum lugar no form, sucesso aí!

Comment: Simm, obrigado. Sucesso aí também! Por mais pessoas prestativas na comunidade.